# Is there an anti derivative to $f(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)}$ in $|z|>4$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, partial-fractions, rational-functions

> Is there an anti derivative function to the complex function
>   $$f(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)}$$ in $|z|>4$?

**My attempt:**
We notice that $f(z)=\frac{z}{z-2}+\frac{z}{1-z}$ (by decomposing to partial fractions). But when I try to guess an anti-derivative function it doesn't go well:
$$
(\ln(\frac{1}{1-z})'=\frac{1}{1-x}
\\(\ln\frac{z}{1-z})'=\frac{1}{x(1-x)}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert=5}f(z)\,\mathrm dz=2\pi i,$$by the residue theorem. If there was such an antiderivative, the integral along any loop would be equal to $0$.

Comment: Is this argument true?
I know that there's a theorem that claims: If $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{C}$ and $\Omega$ is a **convex** domain or a **simply connected domain** then $f$ is analytic if and only if $\int_\gamma f =0$ for all closed simple curve $\gamma\subseteq \Omega$ if and only if $f$ has an anti derivative.
But in our case $\Omega=\{|z|>4\}$ is not simply connected nor convex.

Comment: If $\gamma\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\Omega$ is a loop and $f$ has an antiderivative $F$, then$$\int_\gamma f(t)\,\mathrm dt=F\bigl(\gamma(b)\bigr)-F\bigl(\gamma(a)\bigr)=0,$$since, by the definition of loop, $\gamma(b)=\gamma(a)$.

Comment: @J.Doe This domain isn't simply connected. Which is exactly what allows an integral around a loop like this to be non-zero, which again means that an antiderivative doesn't exist. Any analytic function on a simply connected domain has an antiderivative.

Comment: It's a duplicate: [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f(z)%3D%5Cfrac%7Bz%7D%7B(z-1)(z-2)%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: @MartinR Right. $\ddot\frown$

Comment: @Arthur Why does $\int_{|z|=5} f(z)dz=2\pi i$? We have
$$
\int_{|z|=5}\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{5^2ie^{2it}}{5^2e^{2it}-3\cdot 5e^{it}+2}dt
$$
And we can't use residues since $1,2\notin\Omega$.

Comment: \begin{align}\int_{\lvert z\rvert=5}\frac z{(z-1)(z-2)}\,\mathrm dz&=2\pi i\left(\operatorname{res}_{z=2}\frac z{(z-1)(z-2)}+\operatorname{res}_{z=1}\frac z{(z-1)(z-2)}\right)\\&=2\pi i(2-1)\\&=2\pi i.\end{align}

Comment: @J.Doe We can extend the function analytically to the entire plane minus two points. This doesn't change the integral around your circle, but allows us to use residues.